# fgrep with pattern in fixed positions

Tags: grep

I am having a file x with lines say

```
123
345
789
830
```

I want to grep those line matching these patterns from another file `x1`, but only those lines where these patterns appear in positions `151-153` of the lines in `x1`

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following might work with `bash`:

```
pfx=$(printf %*s 150 | tr ' ' .)
grep -f <(sed -e 's/^/^'"$pfx"'/' x) x1
```

I feel like there should be a better way to do this but they are all more complicated.